# C# - auto-implemented events

Tags: c#, events

In C# there are auto-implemented properties...

```
public int SomeValue { get; set; }
```

But why aren't there auto-implemented events?

```
public event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> SomethingHappened { add; remove; }
```

Comment: The whole point of `add` and `remove` syntax is customization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Events are "auto-events" by default: when you write

```
public event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> SomethingHappened;
```

you get the default behavior for both `add` and `remove`.

Note that C# designers could not use the same syntax for auto-properties because it would collide with field declarations. In addition, they needed to supply syntax for letting you define visibility of `get` and `set` separately, so they invented the `{ get ; set; }` syntax.

Comment: Wow! I never knew that!